# How would I join two identical tables from different data sources using Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to write some pseudocode using the Java DSL to join two identical tables from two different databases.

For example, I have a Person table in MySQL and PostgreSQL databases. Would like to see a union of all rows. Can somebody give any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Update: What I tried is below code in the route definition

```
from(sql:select name, age from person?datasource=xyz).to(direct:foo);
from(sql:select name, age from person?datasource=abc).to(direct:foo);
from(direct:foo).to(stream:out);
```

The above fetches data and combines into a single channel, however, I would like to do operations like remove duplicates, filter rows etc. There I wasn't sure how to do that. Maybe the Aggregator component is needed?

Comment: Hi Ramesh. I have not downvoted your question, but if I had to guess why it was, it's because it's so vague and high-level. Since you're asking an Apache Camel question, people would assume you should already know a lot about writing Apache Camel routes, and if you do, we would like to see what you've tried so far. If you don't know how to write Apache Camel routes, then it's too early to ask this question.

Comment: @DavidS:  Having worked with Camel routes now for about nine months, I can say that questions like this are par for the course.

Comment: @DavidS I updated the original question to be little clear, as a newbie I am learning and I know how to write simple routes, but nothing complicated yet. I wanted to see how one does data integration with camel, as my bigger motive is trying to see if there is a value to bring in http://teiid.io tech as some camel component to do exactly same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems straightforward enough to do - you simply need to keep in mind two things.

- You have data coming from two locations.
- You need to keep the  data from stepping on one another *before* you can aggregate it.

*Then*, and only then, can you aggregate them together.

If I were to take a stab at it, this would be a start.  I'd want to leverage the [SQL component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-sql/src/main/docs/sql-component.adoc)'s ability to specify a specific header in which the SQL result should be stored in.  From there I find it a bit easier to use a simple processor after aggregation to process the two records and perform whatever logic I want with them.

```
from("sql:select name, age from person?datasource=xyz&outputHeader=MySqlDataSet&outputType=Person")
    .to("direct:foo");
from("sql:select name, age from person?datasource=abc&outputHeader=PostgresDataSet&outputType=Person")
    .to("direct:foo");

from("direct:foo")
    .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
    .completionFromBatchConsumer()
    .process(exchange -> {
         // now you have control over the exchange which has both exchanges
         // which has both properties you require.
         // manipulate, merge, and dedupe here to your heart's content.
     });
```